# A strange problem using jquery in IE6

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-6

I am using jquery load method to update divs , it works great until I test my code under IE6.
The problem is : under IE6 , when I click a button to trigger a load method , the page is remaining unchanged until I move my cursor, that means if I click my mouse and keep my hand away from the mouse , the page is unchanged , if I move the mouse , the page is updated.

This problem is only occurred under IE6 . IE7 , IE8, Firefox all have no problem.

Have you guys ever encountered this kind of problem ?

Comment: "Strange" is the middle name of IE 6

Comment: javascript issue in IE6? shocking!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a drawing issue in IE6 when rendering certain types of content, usually involving filters.  You can sometimes trigger a redraw though by doing this, doesn't work in all cases though...welcome to IE:

```
$(window).resize();
```

Comment: @Tony - Need more info then, starting with javascript and html, possibly CSS.  Giving almost no specific info or code...makes it hard to answer any better than the most common cause of the issue.  An unclosed html tag for example creates random behavior as well.  The first step: check that your markup is valid at: http://validator.w3.org/ Run the page and load function, select all, view selection source in firefox, then do direct input validation method at that url (otherwise the ajax loaded content won't be there).